# Inputting data into text box upon click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in which users can talk on a chatroom. My problem is that I have a gallery in which users can select pictures.

My question is how could a user click a html link and for that html link to input text into the input so when the user clicks the link which says `cat` it inputs into the text field `:cat`.

This is the form I have so far:

```
<form method="POST" action="chat.php">
  <input type="text" name="message"></input>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is the gallery:

```
<a href="#"><img src="cat.jpg"/></a>
```

So again, the question is how I could insert text into the text box once the user clicks the image of the cat?

Thank you for anyone who spends time on helping me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a js function and then call it with the anchor to change the value attribute of the input. Input type text should not have a closing tag either.

```js
function changeChatInput(value) {
  document.getElementById('chatInput').value = value;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="chat.php">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="chatInput" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>


<a href="javascript: changeChatInput(':cat');">
  <img src="cat.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank-you for applying it to the example great response.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **jQuery** you could do something like this:

```
$('a.cat').click(function()
{
    $('input[name="message"]').val(':cat');
});
```

In this case you would need to update the link with the following:

```
<a class="cat" href="#"><img src="cat.jpg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in JS (without jQuery):
http://jsbin.com/doqedodezo/3/edit?html,js,output

The image triggers a JS function and passes the text which is supposed to be added to the input field. 
I added a id to the input to address it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
$('a > img').click(function() {
    var imgName = retrieveImgName($(this).attr('src'));
    $('input[name="message"]').val(':' + imgName);
});

var retrieveImgName = function(imgPath) {
    return imgPath.substring(0, imgPath.indexOf('.'));
};
```

Doing that you can extract the logic for retrieving the name based on the `src` attribute of the `img`.
So, if the logic changes for some reason, you can sobstitute it quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your job by using this **jQuery** syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a > img').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('input[name="message"]').val(':cat');
});
</script>
```